# How to calculate the 15 minutes block average starting from 00:00 hours?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I'm trying to calculate the block averages of the iot data coming in from over 200+ devices at every 15 seconds to aws iot core and want to calculate the block average (15 minutes) for each of the device and it's parameters.

Here is my flow :-

`aws iot core (ingestion) -> iot rules engine -> firehose delivery stream (900 seconds buffer and dynamic partioning data based on device name) -> s3 bucket (batched data stored in s3 bucket)`

I want to calculate the average for all devices and its all parameters for eg:-

```
device a has this payload {
    "name" : "a",
    "voltage" : 3.4,
    "power" : 1.23,
    "time" : epoch timestamp
}

device b has this payload {
     "name" : "b",
    "voltage" : 12.90,
    "power" : 54.78,
    "time" : epoch timestamp
    
}
```

I want to calculate and store average for each of the parameter of the device in such a way :-

| Date | Block | Average Voltage | Average power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 - Jan - 2023 | 00:00-00:15 | 23.54 | 32.526 |
| 12 - Jan - 2023 | 00:15-00:30 | 20.36 | 21.90 |
| 12 - Jan - 2023 | 00:30-00:45 | 34.36 | 89.24 |
| 12 - Jan - 2023 | 00:45-01:00 | 56.312 | 78.20 |

There should be 96 blocks for the entire day :-

`1440 minutes in a day / 15 minutes block = 96 blocks in a day`

One way i thought of implementing it is putting a s3 lambda trigger on put event on s3 read files of each entered object from s3 calculate it and store it in another s3 bucket. But it does not seem to work the way i want it to.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't timestamp be in the payload for calculating the block average?

Comment: I'm appending it to the payload in iot rules engine like "select * , timestamp() as time from 'topic' ";

Comment: you might want to consider using AWS Kinesis data analytics with sliding window? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/sliding-window-concepts.html You can run sql query on the incoming data.

Comment: Is there any way to run kinesis data analytics query on the batched data in kinesis firehose?

Comment: I remember you could connect firehose as a source of kinesis data analytics. There are other options as well like iot analytics, timestream or athena.

Comment: Is there any way to send the recently batched file put into s3 bucket by firehose delivery stream to the pyspark emr serverless service and calculate the average there and store it into the new s3 bucket ?